# Using Passport with Next.js / React

Tags: reactjs, passport.js, next.js

What's the traditional method to do OAuth with React? Im showing a bit of my newness with this, but I nailed down how to make a REST API with express that authenticates with passport and syncs the account to a database. The problem im having is I want to have a React website ping the server for OAuth, but then redirect BACK to the React page WITH the OAuth success data and store the cookies on the page for React not the URL for my server. Any help wrapping my head around exactly how this all works would be gladly accepted. Ive been exploring using Next.js as a solution as it seems to be serving up React on a node.js server which means I could substitute serving up a React page route for a template like guides ive seen so far have told me to do.

Answer (score 0):

Your instinct is right that **most** of the work will be on the server side. When dealing with OAuth and OpenID, terminology can get confusing. OpenID is actually just an extension on top of OAuth 2.0 that slightly modifies it to allow for authentication. Otherwise; OAuth is just a mechanism for delegated authorization.

You should check out this video presentation ["OAuth 2.0 and OpenID Connect (in plain English)"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=996OiexHze0). It is one of the best explanations that goes into more detail about what I just said. It got me on the right track to understand more.

As simple as it may be in theory, actually implementing this stuff can be a pain. Depending on your language, framework, and available libraries, having a library do too much of the work for you can be just as confusing.

There are different flows for different use-cases. You can accomplish what you want in a browser-based Javascript SPA, but you're going to need some kind of protected server-side application between the browser and identity provider. Be very careful that you're doing your due diligence.

You may find the the identity provider you are utilizing is asking for additional requirements and parameters on top of the standard. This can be frustrating when dealing with a framework that doesn't know about these requirements.

I recently put together a [toy project](https://github.com/forgo/login-gov) for `login.gov` because their official example repos were half-baked and assumed your client was running on the server-side. Note that the project is not the browser React app itself, but an API by which it could authenticate. I wrote this in Spring Boot (language: Kotlin).

Spring would be the case where it does a LOT of work for you, but when you need to customize an action, how you do so can be very "magical" and confusing. The benefit of Spring, to me, is that its defaults are fairly strict, and it forces you to understand and question what you are changing before doing so.

On the other hand, we had better luck finding examples of Express.js APIs that worked out of the box or were easier to customize. The problem with those solutions is you may question how lax their defaults are. Furthermore, my job has certain requirements that make deploying Node.js a non-starter.

For the record, when it comes to React and the Javascript ecosystem, I don't think there's any such thing as "traditional" =). Things move so quickly in this realm, but you might say React is still fresh.